# format output from BAT file to console

Tags: batch-file, format, output

I would like this
`echo %%~nxa !newsize! !unit!`
to output so that newsize starts at a specific column on the console. The problem is that %%~nxa is a variable length so adding tabs, or other characters doesn't work.

Is there a way to make newsize start at a specific column or to add tabs based on the length of %%~nxa.

Comment: Assign the `FOR` variable to an environmental variable with spaces added to the end. `set "filename=%%~nxa                              "` Then substring it to whatever you want. `echo !filename:~0,20!`

Comment: Yes, there is a way. The question is, why do you need that? for display output, or for further processing? Is `%%~nxa` supposed to be a file name? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dynamic column formatting function here is something you can use.  You can left and right justify data columns as well.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "filename=ReallyLongFileName.txt"
set "newsize=20,000"
set "unit=300"

call :Format "[30] [20] [10]" "%filename%" "%newsize%" "%unit%"

set "filename=Some Other Long FileName.txt"
set "newsize=200,000"
set "unit=3000"

call :Format "[30] [20] [10]" "%filename%" "%newsize%" "%unit%"

exit /b

REM FUNCTIONS BELOW
:Format Fmt [Str1] [Str2]...
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "fmt=%~1"
set "line="
set "space=                                                                                                    "
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%n in (^"^

^") do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[" %%a in (".!fmt:]=%%~n.!") do (
  if "!!" equ "" endlocal
  set "const=%%a"
  call set "subst=%%~2%space%%%~2"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if %%b0 geq 0 (set "subst=!subst:~0,%%b!") else set "subst=!subst:~%%b!"
  for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%c in ("!line!!const:~1!!subst!") do (
    endlocal
    set "line=%%c"
  )
  shift /2
)
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo(!line!
exit /b
```

Running this code will output

```
ReallyLongFileName.txt         20,000               300
Some Other Long FileName.txt   200,000              3000
```

If you want to right justify the last column just change the 10 to -10 and it will output like this.

```
ReallyLongFileName.txt         20,000                      300
Some Other Long FileName.txt   200,000                    3000
```

You can right justify all the columns if you want. So making all the values negative would output.

```
        ReallyLongFileName.txt               20,000        300
  Some Other Long FileName.txt              200,000       3000
```